# Getting a 400 bad request error while testing

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I'm making a registration form for vendors in my ecom website and, I'm getting a bad request error while doing a post request. I tried to find out what's causing this error, but everything seems to be fine. I've used a template similar to this and it was working fine, but I don't know what's wrong with this one. Take a look at my code and please help me find out the problem.

HTML code :

```
<div class="col">
    <form action="{{ url_for('Vendor_registration') }}" method="post" style="padding-top:1%;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="For eg : Andrew" id="first" maxlength="15">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="middle">Middle Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="middle_name" class="form-control" placeholder="For eg : Jason" id="middle" maxlength="15">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="For eg : Sebastian" id="last" maxlength="15">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact">Contact Number:</label>
                <input type="text" name="contact_no" class="form-control" placeholder="For eg : 0123456789" id="contact" maxlength="10">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email address:</label>
             <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="For eg : abc@abc.com" id="email" maxlength="30">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
             <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="********" id="pwd" maxlength="15">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="shop">Shop Name:</label>
             <input type="text" name="shop_name" class="form-control" placeholder="For eg : abc store" id="shop" maxlength="15">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="certificate">Shop Certificate:</label>
             <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file border" id="certificate">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="account">Bank Account number:</label>
             <input type="text" name="account_no" class="form-control" id="account" maxlength="20">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="upi">UPI ID:</label>
             <input type="text" name="upi_id" class="form-control" id="upi" maxlength="15">
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Submit</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Python code :

```
@app.route("/vendor_register", methods=["GET","POST"])
def Vendor_registration():
    email=str(request.form.get("email"))
    first_name=str(request.form.get("first_name"))
    middle_name=str(request.form.get("middle_name"))
    last_name=str(request.form.get("last_name"))
    shop_name=str(request.form.get("shop_name"))
    phone_no=str(request.form.get("contact_no"))
    password=str(request.form.get("password"))
    account_no=str(request.form.get("account_no"))
    upi_id=str(request.form.get("upi_id"))
    shop_certificate=" "
    file=request.files["image"]
    return "done"
```

logs :

```
└─$ flask run
 * Serving Flask app "application.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production   deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2021 03:13:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2021 03:13:48] "POST /vendor_registration HTTP/1.1" 200  -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Mar/2021 03:13:58] "POST /vendor_register HTTP/1.1" 400 -
^C
```

Comment: Are there any logs from your server? See also: [Debugging Application Errors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/debugging/)

Comment: Oh yes, I've mentioned them now. Take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I actually forgot to mention the mime type which is ' enctype="multipart/form-data" ' in the form, because there was an image also. Now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Might your webserver be running mod_security ?

Comment: No @Calvin Ellis , I'm not running my server with mod_security. Actually I had to specify the correct mimetype for solving this issue. Thank you for giving your time and help.